# Cannot read/access Apache2 access logs

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

I have been asked to take a look at some access logs for an Apcahe2 web server running on Ubuntu. I have been told by the administrator of the machine that my login has "admin" access yet I cannot seem to copy the access logs from Apache2 to my local machine via FTP for analysis.

I figure one of two things is happening ...

1. I don't really have full admin access
2. Some other process (perhaps Apache2) has control of the log files and won't let me copy them.

   How can I tell if I truly have admin access? What type of access do I need to request? Root access? Something else? Should I be able to copy these log files with admin access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that he setup sudo access for your account.  Try `sudo -l`.  That will tell you if you have sudo access (and what commands you can run.)